# How to type a backslash in emacs "\"

Tags: key-bindings, backslash

I'm on Prelude, and there is no way I can type a `\`. I was thinking maybe I should create a keybinding but I don't know how to create it to output a character such as `\`. Any help welcome! Thank you!

Comment: What does `C-h k \ ` tell you?

Comment: What is Prelude? Why is there no way to type a `\\`? Do not expect other people to know what you are talking about just because you can see it: please explain.

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs by default doesn't associate `\` with any command… You should be able to directly type it without any trouble. If you cannot, then you should have a module enabled, which takes it.

If you need further help, please answer the following questions:

- are you using emacs in terminal (in a TTY?) or in graphical mode?
- where do you want to type a backslash? In a document body, in the minibuffer, elsewhere?
- as @phils asks, what does `C-h k \` give you?
- what is your keyboard layout?

Comment: To be more precise, most keys are bound to `self-insert-command`, which is the command that inserts the key you pressed into the buffer.

Comment: Apologies. I managed to find the keyboard binding for that \. Apparently I needed the RIGHT Alt key, not the left one (even though in the Mac Kayboard layout both are giving the backslash). When I type C-h k \ I get "\ runs the command org-self-insert-command (found in org-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in ‘org-9.3.6/org.el’. It is bound to SPC..~, ..\377. (org-self-insert-command N). "

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around you can try `C-q \`.  Try Étienne Deparis answer for a permanent resolution.

Comment: I did not get how to get \ if I can type it :P

Comment: Do you not have a \ key on your keyboard then?

Comment: I resolved this issue. My keyboard produces it outside Emacs when pressing SHIFT+ALT(left or right)+7. I always use ALT(left). Since it did not work in Emacs, I thought something was wrong. Apparently some other keybinding is associated with that combo, but using ALT(right) works.

Comment: I've never encountered such a keyboard.